# Gradle: exclude triggering sub-project task when root task is called

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

I have the following project-structure:

```
Root project 'base'
+--- Project ':server'
+--- Project ':testManager'
```

Each module has its own `artifactoryPublish` task.

How can I exclude execution of `artifactoryPublish` of `testManager` module when I run the root task in the `base` root dir?

`> ./gradlew artifactoryPublish` - this should **not** run the `testManager:artifactoryPublish`.

But I need to be able to run this task separately for one `testmanager` module:

`> ./gradlew`testManager:artifactoryPublish` - this should start the task in specified module.

I tried to add the following to `settings.gradle`:

```
startParameter.excludedTaskNames << ':testManager:artifactoryPublish'
```

But in this case the task is skipped always even if I run it with the module name.

Or maybe there is a way to check if `artifactoryPublish` was called only for `testManager`, otherwise set `artifactoryPublish.skip` flag?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude tasks from running with `-x` switch

```
$> gradle --dry-run artifactoryPublish
:artifactoryPublish SKIPPED
:server:artifactoryPublish SKIPPED
:testManager:artifactoryPublish SKIPPED

$> gradle --dry-run artifactoryPublish -x :testManager:artifactoryPublish
:artifactoryPublish SKIPPED
:server:artifactoryPublish SKIPPED
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that suits my case is to add the following to the testManager build.gradle:

```
artifactoryPublish.onlyIf { 
    ext.has("publishTestFiles") 
}
```

This allows using additional flags only if the launch of this module's task is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add to `build.gradle`  of `testManager` module next script

```
artifactoryPublish.onlyIf { false }
```